# Добавление View программно

Tags: android, android-studio, listview, recyclerview, view

При программном добавлении сразу двух View в макет возникает ошибка такого рода:

```
Process: com.money.evgeny.ShoppingBudget, PID: 14676
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:4310)
at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4146)
at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4087)
at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4060)
at com.money.evgeny.ShoppingBudget.Adapters.RVAdapter_WhatNew.onBindViewHolder(RVAdapter_WhatNew.java:60)
at com.money.evgeny.ShoppingBudget.Adapters.RVAdapter_WhatNew.onBindViewHolder(RVAdapter_WhatNew.java:16)
```

Код ACtivity с RecyclerView (куда добавляю view):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/WhatNewActivity_background"
    tools:context="com.money.evgeny.ShoppingBudget.WhatNewActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_whatnew"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Код адаптера:

```
public class RVAdapter_WhatNew extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RVAdapter_WhatNew.ViewHolder>{
    private List<Item_WhatNew> mas_data;
    LinearLayout card_liner;
    LinearLayout item_text;

    //Класс view holder-а, с помощью которого мы получаем ссылку на каждый элемент пункта списка
    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView tv_item_version;
        TextView tv_item_date;
        TextView tv_item_text;

        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            tv_item_version = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_version);
            tv_item_date = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_date);
            tv_item_text = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_text);
        }
    }

    //Конструктор для данных
    public RVAdapter_WhatNew(List<Item_WhatNew> list){
        this.mas_data = list;
    }

    @Override   //Создает view (вызывается LayoutManager-ом)
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_what_new_activity, parent, false);

        card_liner = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.card_liner);
        item_text = (LinearLayout) View.inflate(v.getContext(), R.layout.sub_item_what_new_activity, null);
        card_liner.addView(item_text);
        card_liner.addView(item_text);

        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override   //Заменяет контент view (вызывается LayoutManager-ом)
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.tv_item_version.setText(mas_data.get(position).version);
        holder.tv_item_date.setText(mas_data.get(position).date);
        holder.tv_item_text.setText(mas_data.get(position).text[0]);
    }

    @Override   //Возвращает размер данных (вызывается LayoutManager-ом)
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mas_data.size();
    }
}
```

Метод в котором происходит программное добавление view и ошибка:

```
@Override   //Создает view (вызывается LayoutManager-ом)
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_what_new_activity, parent, false);

        card_liner = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.card_liner);
        item_text = (LinearLayout) View.inflate(v.getContext(), R.layout.sub_item_what_new_activity, null);
        card_liner.addView(item_text);
        card_liner.addView(item_text);

        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

Необходимо 2 раза вызвать `inflate`, т.к. в вашем случае вы пытаетесь добавить один и тот же `view`

```
@Override 
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_what_new_activity, parent, false);

    card_liner = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.card_liner);
    item_text = (LinearLayout) View.inflate(v.getContext(), R.layout.sub_item_what_new_activity, null);
    item_text2 = (LinearLayout) View.inflate(v.getContext(), R.layout.sub_item_what_new_activity, null);
    card_liner.addView(item_text);
    card_liner.addView(item_text2);

    return new ViewHolder(v);
}
```

Comment: Komdosh, это работает, спасибо) Но мне кажется, это решать нужно каким-то другим путем.

Comment: Смотря что вы хотите вообще сделать ;)

Comment: Komdosh, Есть ACtivity с карточками (CardView). Каждая карточка это Номер версии, Дата, и список изменений в приложении. С версией и датой все просто. Но вот со списком изменений у меня проблема. Ведь он для каждой карточки разный и как заполнять его через RecycleView я не пойму.

Comment: Разный с точки зрения количества элементов или разная разметка view?

Comment: Вам нужен список в элементе списка?

Comment: Komdosh, с точки зрения количества. У первой карточки 2 пункта, у второй 5, у третьей 1 и т.д.

Comment: Flippy, да, именно.

Comment: RecyclerView внутри RecyclerView, как выход :) Ну или что-нибудь попроще вроде ListAdapter

Comment: @Evgeny, а почему не вывести их в одном TextView? Или они должны быть кликабельными, с раскрывающимися подробностями?

Answer (score 0):

Если R.layout.sub_item_what_new_activity - это просто TextView, то можно просто два раза создать его программно. Это будет гораздо быстрее, чем инфлейтить лэйаут (особенно, два раза).

Comment: Замечание по поводу кода: держать ссылку на card_liner и item_text на уровне класса не разумно, так как ViewHolder штука не единичная (их будет +- столько, сколько вмещает экран устройства). card_liner и item_text будет ссылаться на последний созданный ViewHolder.