# Заполненный ListView видно не полностью

Tags: android, android-studio, listview, recyclerview, android-xml

Суть проблемы: Есть карточки - созданные при помощи RecycleView. В каждой карточке список пунктов - созданных с помощью ListView. Все работает, все отображается. НО... Пункты в карточка отображаются не все! Они там есть! Все! Но показывается только первый. Я уже всю разметку прошерстил. Не понимаю, почему отображается только по одному пункту.

Должно быть вот так:

[image: Должно быть вот так:]
А получается вот так (ТО, на что указывают стрелки - это скроллы, что свидетельствует о том, что там еще есть пункты):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] 
Xml-разметка самой карточки:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    app:cardElevation="4dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_item_version"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:paddingBottom="6dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingTop="6dp"
                    android:text="Версия: "
                    android:textColor="#262626"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_item_date"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:paddingBottom="6dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:paddingTop="6dp"
                    android:text="tv_date"
                    android:textColor="#606060"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:background="#90c1c1c1" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/card_liner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="6dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/card_listview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:divider="@android:color/transparent" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Xml-разметка шаблона для одного пункта (которым наполняю карточки с помощью ListView):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:text="-"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_item_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="item_textitem"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Зачем Вам ListView? По-моему здесь достаточно одного TextView.

Comment: Там несколько пунктов. Я не знаю как при помощи одного TextView отобразить несколько пунктов так, как это выглядит на первой картинке. Поясните?

Comment: Собрать в один String  через перенос строки: `String changeLog = change1 + "\n" + change2 + "\n" + change3....` и вставить в TextView

Comment: Хмм. Ну это хоть какой-то выход, пока что. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

ListView в RecycleView - очень странное решение. Думаю, ListView не умеет вычислять свой размер внутри LinearLayout (да и контейнеров вообще). Предлагаю отказаться от ListView и создавать его содержимое программно. Тем более, что лэйаут простой.

```
float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

for(String change : changes) {
    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(context);
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

    TextView prefix = new TextView(context);
    prefix.setText("-");
    prefix.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 18);
    prefix.setPadding((int) (4 * density), 0, 0, 0);
    layout.addView(prefix);

    TextView text = new TextView(context);
    text.setText(change);
    text.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 18);
    layout.addView(
            text, 
            new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            )
    );
    root.addView(layout);  // где root - это лэйаут с id = card_liner (только поменяйте у него android:orientation на vertical)
}
```

Я уверен, что это в целом упростит код и сделает его более производительным.

Comment: Это не подходит, т.к. при таком решении я снова возвращаюсь к вот такой проблеме: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/734616/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-view-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE

Comment: Так вы оберните всё это дело в цикл и будет вам счастье ) Сейчас попробую проиллюстрировать в виде кода.

Comment: Обновил свой ответ